# Google Cloud Logging export to Big Query does not seem to work

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

I am using the the google cloud logging web ui to export google compute engine logs to a big query dataset. According to the docs, you can even create the big query dataset from this web ui (It simply asks to give the dataset a name). It also automatically sets up the correct permissions on the dataset.

It seems to save the export configuration without errors but a couple of hours have passed and I don't see any tables created for the dataset. According to the docs, exporting the logs will stream the logs to big query and will create the table with the following template:

my_bq_dataset.compute_googleapis_com_activity_log_YYYYMMDD

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#log_entries_in_google_bigquery

I can't think of anything else that might be wrong. I am the owner of the project and the dataset is created in the correct project (I only have one project).

I also tried exporting the logs to a google storage bucket and still no luck there. I set the permissions correctly using gsutil according to this:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export#setting_product_name_short_permissions_for_writing_exported_logs

And finally I made sure that the 'source' I am trying to export actually has some log entries.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ingested any log entries since configuring the export? Cloud Logging only exports entries to BigQuery or Cloud Storage that arrive after the export configuration is set up. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#exported_logs_availability.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have given edit permission for 'cloud-logs@google.com' in the Big Query console. Refer [this.](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export)

Comment: Hello. It would be better if you could post the info on the site for users to read. If that link changes, your answer will become quite useless. Cheers.